# Using Aura attribute variable in static resource

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, aura, static-resources, aura-attribute

I have some aura attributes on my Aura component

```
<aura:attribute name="appName" default="servicePortalVar" type="String"/>
```

I would like to use this variable "appName" in my static resource JS file. For example -

```
let utag_data = {
       app_name: "{!v.appName}"
   }
```

Is it possible to replace static resource variables value with Aura attribute variable values?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do this directly. You can, however, communicate through various means, such as sessionStorage/onstorage, postMessage/onmessage, or even just setting a property on the window object (e.g. `window.appName = component.get("v.appName")`). You can theoretically use `component.getReference("v.appName")` as well if you need it to be reactive, but such a technique is undocumented. Your imported script could also just attach a method to the window object (`window.setAppName = function(value) { ... }`) that your Aura code can call after it gets the `afterScriptsLoaded` event.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox. I was also thinking if a windows post based communication may help (messageevent).
Sending the dynamic values from aura after it is loaded using windows post and static resource js file listening to the event?

Comment: @KaushikRay Yes, that's an available option. You can also use a sort of pub-sub model that you could import as a static resource, as well.